# create object from array, using recursion/reduce?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm just kind of lousy with recursive functions.

I want to turn this...

```
const input = { regions: ["US", "CA", "LA"], checked: true };
```

...into the following, using recursion and `reduce`:

```
const output = {
  US: {
    CA: {
      LA: true
    }
  }
};
```

Help?  I've tried lots of things, but my experiments are too embarrassing to share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the regions with `reduceRight`, creating the nested object with an initial value of the `checked` property, and surrounding it with the new object (the new accumulator) on every iteration:

```js
const input = { regions: ["US", "CA", "LA"], checked: true };
const { regions, checked } = input;

const output = regions.reduceRight((a, prop) => ({ [prop]: a }), checked);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need recursion here (and I would favour `.reduceRight`), but, here is a different approach which uses a recursive function in case you're interested in how it could be done. You can destructure the first element from your array and use it as the key, then, set the value to the next call which would produce an object. If no key can be retrieved, you can return the value of `checked`:

```js
const input = { regions: ["US", "CA", "LA"], checked: true };
const getNested = ([key, ...r], end) => key ? {[key]: getNested(r, end)} : end;

console.log(getNested(input.regions, input.checked));
```